# Can you unset() many variables at once in PHP?

Tags: php, unset

I have a pretty high traffic social network site,
 I would like to get into the habit of unsetting large array and mysql object and even some string variables.

So is it possible to unset more then 1 item in PHP

example:

```
<?PHP

unset($var1);

// could be like

unset($var1,$var2,$var3);

?>
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes.

Your example will work just as you imagine.
The method signature for [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) is as follows:

```
void unset ( mixed $var [, mixed $var [, mixed $... ]] )
```

Answer (score 13):

[The PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) can be very handy.  You can search for any built-in function and get a pretty detailed description of what that function does, etc.  And the answer is yes, you can supply `unset` with as many variables as you want.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, see the PHP manual, Example 1:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

Answer (score 0):

Also you can extend any PHP function, look at example

```
function multiply_foo()
{
    foreach(func_get_args() AS $arg)
        foo($arg);
}

multiply_foo($arg1, $arg2, $arg3);
```

*via* [PHP: func_get_args](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)