# Unset group of variables

Tags: php, variables, null, unset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you unset() many variables at once in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275766/can-you-unset-many-variables-at-once-in-php)

```
$var1 = $var2 = $tvar3 = null;
```

**Is it okay to remove variables like this?**

Are there better ways to unset couple of variables?

Comment: are you sure you really want to unset variables in great numbers?

Comment: @Col: Think of it as... variable genocide :P

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275766/can-you-unset-many-variables-at-once-in-php

Comment: I think of it as a design flaw

Comment: @Shakti Singh: You realize you have enough rep to vote to close? Anyway, good find. I just threw in my close vote.

Comment: @BoltClock: Exceeded the daily limit to vote to close question

Comment: @Shakti Singh: I see, fair enough.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`unset()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) is variadic (i.e. it takes any number of arguments and unsets them all):

```
unset($var1, $var2, $var3);
```

Also note that `unset()` is not the same as setting to `NULL`. Using `unset()` you actually remove the variables, whereas setting them to `NULL` keeps them defined, just with a "value" of `NULL`. Doing it either way causes `isset()` to return false on those variables, but they're still semantically and technically different.

Here's a quick proof:

```
<?php

$x = NULL;
var_dump(array_key_exists('x', $GLOBALS)); // bool(true)

unset($x);
var_dump(array_key_exists('x', $GLOBALS)); // bool(false)

?>
```

Comment: For the record, if anyone wants me to delete my answer just say so in a comment instead of downvoting or revoking upvotes. And even then I'll probably refuse because only this question has the `= NULL` vs `unset()` conundrum which I've taken the liberty to explain here even before the duplicate was found. Unless, of course, someone finds an older question asking about it.