# unsetting a group of environmental variables

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables

I have an situation where there are some number ~ 10 - 30 of environmental variables which pertain to a specific application.  Before re-configuring and re-compiling the application I want to remove (i.e. unset) all relevant env vars.  The list is too annoying to type out explicitly, so I'd like some automation.

I've looked at  [Unset group of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907029/unset-group-of-variables) but it seems to be not quite what I want.

I came up with the below command, which shows what I want to do in principle (unset all environmental variables with "G4" in the names -- actually it's not quite perfect it will unset it if it has "G4" in the values too).

```
printenv |grep G4 |awk 'BEGIN{FS="=";}{system("unset "$1);}'
```

As I should have expected, this doesn't affect the parent shell, which is the behaviour I want.  I have encountered this before, in those cases I've used 'source', but I can't quite see how to do that here. It does not work to put the above command in a shell script and then source that, it seems.

I know I can just find out what's setting those variables in the first place and remove it and open another shell but I don't consider that a solution (although it's probably what I'll do while this question is being answered). I also don't want to unset them one-by-one, that's annoying and it seems like that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: the link you posted is for php, of course it's not what you want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's nearly right. What you need to do is to get those commands out into the parent shell, and the way to do that is with [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html). First print out the names of the variables. Your `awk` command is one way to do that:

```
printenv |grep G4 |awk 'BEGIN{FS="=";}{print $1;}'
```

Then use command substitution to feed the output to the shell:

```
unset $(printenv |grep G4 |awk 'BEGIN{FS="=";}{print $1;}')
```

The `$(...)` gives the output of the command to the shell,  exactly as if you had typed it. I say "almost" because the shell processes the output a little, for instance removing newlines. In this case that's fine, because the `unset` command can take the name of multiple variables to unset. In cases where it would be a problem, quote the output using double quotes: `"$(....)"`. The link gives all the details.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
unset `printenv |grep G4 |awk 'BEGIN{FS="=";}{printf("%s ",$1);}'`
```

And I guess it's related to the answer for: [Unset group of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907029/unset-group-of-variables)

I just didn't realize it

Comment: No, the link you posted is not related at all: it's for php whereas the question is for the shell

Answer (score -1):

```
declare -a vars_to_unset=(blue green red)
unset ${vars_to_unset[@]}
```

Will unset `$blue`, `$green` and `$red` at once.

Extending to the variables containing `G4`:

```
declare -a arr=($(env | cut -d= -f1 | grep G4))
unset ${arr[@]}
```