# How to unset multiple variables?

Tags: php, variables, unset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you unset() many variables at once in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275766/can-you-unset-many-variables-at-once-in-php)

I have 3 variables `var1` `var2` `var3`. Is there's a way of un-setting them without repeated use of `unset()` function ?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

try this

```
unset($foo1, $foo2, $foo3);
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `foreach` loop for this. Since it works with a copy of array.

**See Example**

[**http://codepad.org/mZOc81J5**](http://codepad.org/mZOc81J5)

IF you want to do this using loop then use `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

use like this

```
for($i=0 ; $i<count($array) ; $i++)
{
    unset($array[$i]);
}
```

You have to use `for` loop for this.

you can use `foreach` loop but it will not unset all variable one variable still remains.

```
foreach($array as $arr)
{
    unset($array[$arr]);
}
```